# Count arguments in Lisp

Tags: lisp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determining function argument list in Common Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353661/determining-function-argument-list-in-common-lisp)

Is there a way in Lisp to determine how many arguments a function takes?  What I'm looking for is a function or macro that takes a function and returns the number of arguments it needs.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353661/determining-function-argument-list-in-common-lisp