# Dtrace from Touretzky

Tags: common-lisp, ccl

I am trying to learn lisp with the book "Common LISP a Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation" written by Touretzky. There is a utility in the book, [Dtrace](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Edst/Lisp/dtrace/)(I use *dtrace.generic*). Example of using *dtrace*:

```
(defun add-to-end (x y)
  (append x (list y)))
(defun repeat-first (phrase)
  (add-to-end phrase (first phrase)))
> (dtrace add-to-end repeat-first)
(ADD-TO-END REPEAT-FIRST)
> (repeat-first ’(for whom the bell tolls))
----Enter REPEAT-FIRST
|     PHRASE = (FOR WHOM THE BELL TOLLS)
|   ----Enter ADD-TO-END
|   |     X = (FOR WHOM THE BELL TOLLS)
|   |     Y = FOR
|    \--ADD-TO-END returned
|          (FOR WHOM THE BELL TOLLS FOR)
 \--REPEAT-FIRST returned
      (FOR WHOM THE BELL TOLLS FOR)
(FOR WHOM THE BELL TOLLS FOR)
```

Unfortunately in **Clozure** (on Win7) the result is:

```
? (repeat-first '(for whom the bell tolls))
----Enter REPEAT-FIRST
|     Arg-1 = (FOR WHOM THE BELL TOLLS)
|   ----Enter ADD-TO-END
|   |     Arg-1 = (FOR WHOM THE BELL TOLLS)
|   |     Arg-2 = FOR
|    \--ADD-TO-END returned (FOR WHOM THE BELL TOLLS FOR)
 \--REPEAT-FIRST returned (FOR WHOM THE BELL TOLLS FOR)
(FOR WHOM THE BELL TOLLS FOR)
```

Function argument names are lost. It should depend on the *fetch-arglist* function. Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353661/determining-function-argument-list-in-common-lisp), I wrote *fetch-arglist* as:

```
(defun fetch-arglist (x) (arglist x))
```

In fact:

```
? (arglist #'add-to-end)
(X Y)
:ANALYSIS
```

Unfortunately, the result is the same. Is there a way, in **Clozure**, to make the argument names of functions appear in *dtrace*?

**Update**:
Solution is (in *dtrace.generic*):

```
(defun fetch-arglist (x) (ccl:arglist x))
```

**Update2**:
*dtrace* prints strange results as:

```
((CCC (? AAA . #1=(0)) (? BBB . #1#)))
```

While trace of Clozure prints correctly:

```
 ((CCC (? AAA 0) (? BBB 0)))
```

**Update3**(and hopefully last):
Solution due to Vsevolod Dyomkin:

```
(defparameter *dtrace-print-circle* nil)
```

`*print-circle*` shows [common substructure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791982/changing-copies-of-lists-in-lisp/26792893#26792893):

```
CL-USER> (setf *print-circle* t)
T

CL-USER> (let ((l '((a b c) (d e f))))
           (list l (copy-list l)))
;=> ((#1=(A B C) #2=(D E F)) (#1# #2#))
```

Comment: what does `show-arglist` return? Are you sure it's properly defined in the right package? I tried the code on Linux and it works just fine

Comment: You are right. I had to write ccl:arglist. Unfortunately, I am still unfamiliar with the modules.

Comment: You should be looking at [`dtrace.mcl`](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Edst/Lisp/dtrace/dtrace.mcl), since Clozure Common Lisp grew from Macintosh Common Lisp.

Comment: See also printv: https://github.com/danlentz/printv

Comment: @adabsurdum dtrace.mcl works after replacing *special-form-p* with *special-operator-p*. However it has the same problems reported in update2

Comment: That is controlled by `*print-circle*`. You'll have to wrap `(let ((*print-circle* nil)) ...)` around the code that performs the actual printing. Probably, in `display-one-arg`